# iPhone: How to Close MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, delegates

I'm having difficulties closing an email message that I have raised.

The email opens nicely, but once it is opened it will not close as the mailComposeController:mailer didFinishWithResult:result error:error handler never gets invoked.

As far as I can tell I have all the bits in place to be able to do this.

Anyone any ideas of what I can look at?

Here is how I raise the email:

```
-(IBAction)emailButtonPressed 
{
```

NSString *text = @"My Email Text";

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 mailer.delegate = self;

 [mailer setSubject:@"Note"];
 [mailer setMessageBody:text isHTML:NO];
 [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
 [mailer release];
}
```

and later in the class I have this code to handle the close (but it never gets called):

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)mailer didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
 [self becomeFirstResponder];
 [mailer dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

My header file is defined as:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Thanks

Iphaaw

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are setting the delegate wrong, the delegate property in `MFMailComposeViewController` is called mailComposeDelegate, so it should be:

```
mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

Another possible error I can see is calling `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` on `mailer` - you should send this message to the view controller who presented the mail interface - `self` in this case:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I wrote "possible error" because it might actually work if iOS routes the message through responder chain, anyway - the documentation says it should be send to presenter.

Comment: Thanks too - I had the same problem (kept thinking it was my declaration of self as weak self, turned out to be the delegate setup line!) :)