# Can't dismiss MFMailComposeViewController in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

The `MFMailComposeViewController` cannot be dismissed after pressing cancel or send button. I have added `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` in my class but still, it's not working?

Here is my code:

```
func sendEmail() {
    let MailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    MailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    MailVC.setToRecipients(["\(emailLabel?.text)"])
    MailVC.setSubject("Set your subject here!")
    MailVC.setMessageBody("Hello this is my message body!", isHTML: false)
    // Present the view controller modally.
    self.present(MailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                           didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: check once delegate called properly or not https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305421/how-to-close-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Answer (score 5):

Delegate method signature is wrong. You are missing `_` before `controller` parameter. Try this.

```
public func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And make sure this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController ,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
```